# Difference between a "node" and an "input" in a neural network

Tags: neural-network

I am reading an article which is opened with the sentence:

> We concider a 2-layer, 3-node, n-input neural network whose nodes compute linear threshold functions of their inputs.

I don't understand how is it possible for a neural network to have **3** nodes but **n** inputs. For my understanding, a "neuron" is a "node". So there're n input nodes (first layer) and x output nodes (second layer) and the sentence arguing n+x=3.

What do I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this 2-layer NN in the picture. This has:

- 3 inputs
- 2-layer with 4 nodes
- and 1 output

When we say "an n-layer NN" we are counting its hidden layers (because obviously it has input and output so don't need to be count).
[image]

Comment: So when we consider a 2-layer, 3-node, n-input neural network it basically a NN which have n nodes in the input layer, t nodes in the first layer where t=1 or t=2, 3-t nodes in the second layer and m nodes in the output layer where m is a positive integer. Am I right?

Comment: @J.Doe Why `t` nodes in the first layer? I say we have 3 nodes in both the first hidden layer and the second one. the picture is 2-layer, 4-node.